# TOC links becomes invalid or point to wrong pages after Pdftk cat

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have two pdf files (cover.pdf , content.pdf) which I am joining using pdftk. TOC defined in content.pdf are broken/invalid after merge.

I am looking for anyway to fix or avoid the problem

`pdftk  cover.pdf content.pdf cat output full.pdf`